# RTK Toolkit how to use builder syntax with action creators with createSlice?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm experienced in Redux but I'm totally new to Redux Toolkit (RTK) and `createSlice`. I'm trying to follow tutorials on official RTK Query docs but I'm getting lost.

I've created my actions: (assume there is a type called 'Model')

```js
const setModel = createAction<Model>('setModel');
```

Then I've defined my state:

```js
type MyState = {
  model: Model;
}

const initialState: MyState = {
  model: models[0], // points to a valid object of type Model
};
```

Then I try to create my slice:

```js
export const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'x',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
        
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(setModel, (state, action) => {
      state.model = action.payload;
      return state;
    });
  },
});
```

The docs seem to recommend the `extraReducers` approach to use with action objects and builder directly, which also seems to implicitly support Immer. So I wrote my simple case for `setModel`. However, when I try to use it in a component:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(mySlice.actions.setModel(pickedItem));
```

`mySlice.actions` is empty and doesn't include an entry named `setModel`. It's *not* a TypeScript issue, putting a breakpoint when running also reveals that it's indeed empty:

[image]

Then I've read more and heard that `extraReducers` doesn't create action creators, whereas `reducers` does (which probably explains why my actions are empty). However, then I can't use the builder syntax which RTK Toolkit recommends in the first place.

At this point I'm totally lost.

How can I use `createSlice` with strongly-typed and autogenerated action creators, or if that's not possible, what's the recommended pattern for `createSlice`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use createSlice with strongly-typed and autogenerated action
> creators?

You can type the payloads of the reducers in the slice, the actions will be generated for you, and be correctly typed.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type MyState = {
  model: Model;
}

const initialState: MyState = {
  model: models[0],
};

const mySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'x',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setModel: (state, PayloadAction<Model>) => {
      state.model = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setModel
} = mySlice.actions;

export default mySlice.reducer;
```

The `extraReducers` are primarily used to handle ***external*** actions, e.g. asynchronous actions and actions generated by other slices.